# Error after running compile and upgrade cmd line

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, magento-2.0.4

I am getting an error after running these two cmd line

1. `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`
2. `/usr/local/php55/bin/php-cli bin/magento setup:di:compile`

ERROR BELOW

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
> 'Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException' with message 'Can't
> create directory
> /home/dme/public_html/magento204/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/ResourceConnection/.'
> in
> /home/dme/public_html/magento204/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator.php:103
> Stack trace: #0
> /home/dme/public_html/magento204/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator/Autoloader.php(35):
> Magento\Framework\Code\Generator->generateClass('Magento\Framewo...')
>
> ## 1 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Code\Generator\Autoloader->load('Magento\Framewo...')
>
> ## 2 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call('Magento\Framewo...') #3 /home/dme/public_html/magento204/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php(19):
>
> ReflectionClass->__construct('Magento\Framewo...') #4
> /home/dme/public_html/magento204/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php(44):
> Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor('Magento\Framewo...')
>
> ## 5 /home/dme/public_html/magento204/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectMana
>
> in
> /home/dme/public_html/magento204/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator.php
> on line 103

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a permissions problem.

I suggest you run the following command and try again:

```
chmod -R 770 var/
```

More information about M2 permissions can be found here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html